# Egg-and-chicken problem: need the VLAN package to install the VLAN package

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, network-manager, vlan

**Hello everyone!**

I have installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 in na Hyper-V VM (please, no flack, not my fault...)  and this particular network is a VLAN. No other traffic is permitted through the relevant switch, only that one VLAN id (let's say, 39).

So... I have no connectivity to the internet to apt-get the vlan package, but without the vlan package I can't set up eth0.39 to get internet connectivity. **A nasty egg/chicken problem.**

I can't even download the sole package to another machine on the same subnet, because without the vlan setting on my eth0 I can't even access neighbouring machines.

I have no access to the Hypervisor disks also, so I can't mount them.

What sould I do?

Comment: You should be able to add a VLAN interface manually, then install the `vlan` package. Try with `ip link add link eth0 name eth0.39 type vlan id 39`, Then `ip link set eth0.39 up` and configure your IP no the device.

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I really though this would only work with the `vlan` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on Thomas' comment actually Works (and I quote):

> You should be able to add a VLAN interface manually, then install the
>   vlan package.
>
> Try with
>
> `ip link add link eth0 name eth0.39 type vlan id 39`
>
> then
>
> `ip link set eth0.39 up`
>
> and configure your IP on the device.

BUT...

If you are using Microsoft's Hyper-V, you can simply configure it on Hyper-V and let your Ubuntu be oblivious about the whole VLAN business. You can do it on the Hyper-V Manager software or using the new (web-based) Windows Admin Center.

**For Hyper-V Manager**

1. Open Hyper-V Manager.
2. In the results pane, under `Virtual Machines`,
   select the appropriate virtual machine and then right-click
   `Settings`.
3. Under Hardware, select an virtual switch that's set up
       with a VLAN.
4. In the right pane, select `Enable virtual LAN identification`, and then type the same `VLAN ID` as the one you specified for the virtual switch.

**For Windows Admin Center**

5. Open Windows Admin Center with your browser
6. Click on the machine that hosts your VM
7. Click on `Virtual Machines > Inventory`
8. Click on the desired VM
9. Click on `More > Configuration`
10. Click on `Network`
11. In the `VLAN Identifier`field, inform the apropriate VLAN ID.
12. Click `Save`

Your Ubuntu VM on Hyper-V is now networking on the correct VLAN without even noticing.

Comment: +1 but please remember to accept your answer by clicking check mark next to it.

Comment: Oops, done!!!!!